# I have an unknown error in my Java calculator code

Tags: java, parsing, math, methods, calculator

I am a very young and inexperienced Java programmer trying to understand some of the concepts discussed in my high school computer science class.

Currently, I am trying to make a calculator using Java, but have come across an error in my code...I have been trying to figure out the cause of the problem but I am absolutely stuck. I am trying to create a calculator that has users enter an equation on one line, and through parsing, the program should be able to give me a correct answer. Currently I have only programmed the math to calculate equations with two operands (+,-,*,/,^), but I also want my program to calculate equations with single operands (absolute value, sin, cos, tan).

Here is what I have so far:

```
package calculator;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {

public class Maths {

    double add(double a, double b) {
        double answer = a+b;
        return answer;          
    }

    double subtract(double a, double b) {
        double answer = a-b;
        return answer;          
    }

    double multiply(double a, double b) {
        double answer = a*b;
        return answer;          
    }

    double divide(double a, double b) {
        double answer = a/b;
        return answer;          
    }

    double power(double a, double b){
        double answer =a;

        for (int x=2; x<=b; x++){
            answer *= a;
        }

        return answer;
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    Maths maths = Maths();

    double answer = 0;
    double inputA, inputB;
    char operator;
    boolean done = false;

     while (done == false) {
        System.out.print("Please enter your equation: ");

        inputA = input.nextDouble();
        operator = input.next().charAt(0);
        inputB = input.nextDouble();        

        if (operator == '+') {
            answer = maths.add(inputA, inputB);
        }

        if (operator == '-') {
            answer = maths.subtract(inputA, inputB);
        }

        if (operator == '*') {
            answer = maths.multiply(inputA, inputB);
        }

        if (operator == '/') {
            answer = maths.divide(inputA, inputB);
        }

        if (operator == '^') {
            answer = maths.power(inputA, inputB);
        }

            System.out.println(answer);             
    }       

    input.close();

  }

}
```

As of right now, I feel as though my code is headed in the right direction: except there is a significant error, the cause of which I am unsure. `public class Maths` is not working in my main block of code. When I was creating this, I had the idea that I would use procedural decomposition and make a separate method where the computation would take place, while the actual collection of variables would happen in the main class.

My IDE is giving me an error at `Maths maths = Maths();` located in the main class.

I would really appreciate it if I could get some help on figuring out and understanding the root of the problem at hand so I can fix my program and can avoid such mistakes in the future!

Thank's in advance

Comment: We cannot instantiate `Math`. Its final.

Comment: It is not a `final` class

Comment: @Tirath it is `Maths` not `Math`

Comment: 1) Assuming your source file is named `Calculator.java`, you should *DELETE* the line "public class Maths".  Your Class is either "public class Calculator" or "public class Maths" (the same as your source file), but not both.  2) You need `Calculator maths = new Calculator();`.  NOTE: you may have two classes in a source file, but only one can be "public".  In general, it's usually best to have one one class (the public class) per source file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this code it will work

```
package calculator;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Maths {

    double add(double a, double b) {
        double answer = a+b;
        return answer;          
    }

    double subtract(double a, double b) {
        double answer = a-b;
        return answer;          
    }

    double multiply(double a, double b) {
        double answer = a*b;
        return answer;          
    }

    double divide(double a, double b) {
        double answer = a/b;
        return answer;          
    }

    double power(double a, double b){
        double answer =a;

        for (int x=2; x<=b; x++){
            answer *= a;
        }

        return answer;
    }

}

public class Calculator {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    Maths maths = new Maths();

    double answer = 0;
    double inputA, inputB;
    char operator;
    boolean done = false;

     while (done == false) {
        System.out.print("Please enter your equation: ");

        inputA = input.nextDouble();
        operator = input.next().charAt(0);
        inputB = input.nextDouble();        

        if (operator == '+') {
            answer = maths.add(inputA, inputB);
        }

        if (operator == '-') {
            answer = maths.subtract(inputA, inputB);
        }

        if (operator == '*') {
            answer = maths.multiply(inputA, inputB);
        }

        if (operator == '/') {
            answer = maths.divide(inputA, inputB);
        }

        if (operator == '^') {
            answer = maths.power(inputA, inputB);
        }

            System.out.println(answer);             
    }       

    input.close();

  }

}
```

Comment: You have change the inner class to separate class. No needs to do that. You can just use `Maths maths =new Calculator().new Maths();`

Comment: This code worked in fixing all the bugs, but the program doesn't work...if I try to enter an equation the program crashes

Comment: How are you entering the equation?

Comment: @PrabhatRai I want the program to have the user simply type in the 2 operand equation all at once, for example: 1+1

Comment: use 1 + 1, and try once notice the spaces before and after the operand

Comment: @PrabhatRai Thank you, this worked perfectly! Just out of curiosity, why are the spaces necessary for the program to work properly?

Comment: the next()/nextDouble() methods expect that a token is completed when a enter or a space is encountered.so when you were trying to enter without any spaces like 2+2 then it was throwing error.

Answer (score 3):

You missed the `new` here

```
Maths maths = Maths();
```

It should be

```
Maths maths = new Maths();
```

This `Maths` is an inner class. So you needs to change the instantiation as follows to corrected all errors.

```
Maths maths =new Calculator().new Maths();
```

Comment: Thanks! But when I added the "new" the IDE is giving me the following error: "non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context"